# How to abort tacked tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to create a task tracker in C#. Each task has a unique id/name and a Task that would run "one instance per id can run at the same time.

I created the following class to track tasks

```
public partial class ProgressTracker : IProgressTracker
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, TrackedProgress> _tracker;

    public ProgressTracker()
    {
        _tracker = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TrackedProgress>();
    }

    public bool TryStart(string name, Task task)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }

        return _tracker.TryAdd(name, new TrackedProgress(task));
    }


    public bool TryFinish(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }

        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryRemove(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsRunning(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryGetValue(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool TryAbort(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryGetValue(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            if(!progress.Job.IsCanceled && !progress.Job.IsCompleted)
            {
                // How can I abort progress.Job task

            }
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the class that contains the data about the tracked task.

```
public sealed class TrackedProgress
{
    internal DateTime StartedAt { get; set; }

    public Task Job { get; set; }

    public int? Duration { get; set; }

    public TrackedProgress(Task job)
    {
        StartedAt = DateTime.Now;
        Job = job;
    }

    public TrackedProgress(DateTime startedAt, Task job)
    {
        StartedAt = startedAt;
        Job = job;
    }
}
```

Since I am tracking a `Task`, how can I abort it upon request?

Comment: Tasks can only be “aborted” cooperatively. A CancellationToken approach often works well (both for the task *and* propagated to the code inside the task which will *keep running* if it doesn’t cooperatively terminate).

Comment: See also [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

Comment: There's no `Task.Abort` or `Task.Kill` method. It just doesn't exist, because it would destabilize the system. So you have to implement a method to cooperatively terminate it (`CancellationToken` works, or just a simple bool).

Comment: So what if I track CancellationToken along with the task in the `TrackedProgress`, how can I send a cancel request?

Answer (score 0):

You can add cts to the TrackedProgress class:

```
public sealed class TrackedProgress
{
    internal DateTime StartedAt { get; set; }

    public Task Job { get; set; }

    public CancellationTokenSource Cts { get; }

    public int? Duration { get; set; }

    public TrackedProgress(Task job, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        StartedAt = DateTime.Now;
        Job = job;
        Cts = cts;
    }

    public TrackedProgress(DateTime startedAt, Task job, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        StartedAt = startedAt;
        Job = job;
        Cts = cts;
    }
}
```

And few changes in ProgressTracker:

```
public partial class ProgressTracker
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, TrackedProgress> _tracker;

    public ProgressTracker()
    {
        _tracker = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TrackedProgress>();
    }

    //Here - add the cts
    public bool TryStart(string name, Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }

        return _tracker.TryAdd(name, new TrackedProgress(task, cts));
    }


    public bool TryFinish(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }

        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryRemove(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsRunning(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryGetValue(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool TryAbort(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryGetValue(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            if(!progress.Job.IsCanceled && !progress.Job.IsCompleted)
            {
                // Cancelling the task
                progress.Cts.Cancel();
            }
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Of course you need to make sure you handle cancellation inside the task body too!**

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I tweaked my consumer class which import data which may take time. This class will accept a task and a cancellation token. The cancellation token is tracked along with the Task

The tracker class class now looks like this

```
internal sealed class TrackedProgress
{
    public DateTime StartedAt { get; private set; }

    public Task Job { get; private set; }
    public CancellationTokenSource CancellationToken { get; private set; }
    public int? Duration { get; private set; }

    public TrackedProgress(Task job, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        : this(DateTime.Now, job, cancellationToken)
    {
    }

    public TrackedProgress(DateTime startedAt, Task job, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        StartedAt = startedAt;
        Job = job;
        CancellationToken = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        CancellationToken?.Cancel();
    }

    public bool IsRunning()
    {
        if (Job == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return !Job.IsCompleted && !Job.IsCanceled;
    }
}
```

The tracker class was modified to this

```
public partial class ProgressTracker : IProgressTracker
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, TrackedProgress> _tracker;

    public ProgressTracker()
    {
        _tracker = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TrackedProgress>();
    }

    public bool TryStart(string name, Task task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }
        return _tracker.TryAdd(name, new TrackedProgress(task, cancellationToken));
    }


    public bool TryFinish(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }

        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryRemove(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            if(progress.IsRunning())
            {
                return false;
            }

            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsTracked(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryGetValue(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool TryAbort(string name, out int? duration)
    {
        duration = null;

        if (_tracker.TryGetValue(name, out TrackedProgress progress))
        {
            if(progress.IsRunning())
            {
                progress.Abort();
            }
            duration = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(progress.StartedAt).TotalSeconds;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```